# Does <http:outbound-gateway> support http PATCH method?

Tags: spring-integration

does http:outbound-gateway support http PATCH method? I am using 3.0.2 version of Spring integration.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration HTTP module is fully based on Spring MVC. Hance, if the last one from your CLASSPATH supports **PATCH** method, the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` does it, too.

Under the nutshell of `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` there is `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`, who delegates the hard work to the `RestTemplate`, which, in turn, constructs an `HttpRequest` using `ClientHttpRequestFactory`. And the real implementation for concrete HTTP Method is really depends of that `factory`.

The more later version of Spring and its dependencies you use, the more chances that will work what you want.